# How to get a cronjob to execute 3 days, and 2 days break?

Tags: cron

I want a script to execute 3 days in a row, and then 2 days not, and then 3 days again.
I think this does it, but I'm not sure.

> 00 22 1-31/5,2-31/5,3-31/5 * *

How the first 10 days (2 loop) would look:

01/01/2021  On

01/02/2021  On

01/03/2021  On

01/04/2021  Off

01/05/2021  Off

01/06/2021  On

01/07/2021  On

01/08/2021  On

01/09/2021  Off

01/10/2021  Off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this works like I intended. A loop of [3:2] days.